# ReactTable v6 drag row or move up and down React

Tags: reactjs, drag, reactable, react-table-v6

Has anyone using **react table v6** been able to move a row up or down by dragging it? Is it possible?

I am using react table v6 and bulma css.

Comment: Yes it is possible in react-table.

Comment: how? because for this version in dont found nothing.

Comment: You have to use react-beautiful-dnd with react-table

Comment: you have some example?